# count first list elements whith index

Tags: python, arrays, list, random, indexing

```
import random
n=[0]*7
for i in range(7):
    n[i]=random.randint(0,99)
print(*n,sep=' ')
summa=0
for i in range(7):
    if n.index(7)<4:
        summa=summa+n[i]
print(summa)
```

Here is my code how i can count together first 4 elements of my list all i get is that the number in n.index is not in the list can somoune help like if it outputs numbers 12 43 43 2
56 98 71 i need to count together numbers 12+43+43+2 and then i need to multiply rest numbers that are left 56, 98 and 71
I have tried puting diffrent numbers in n.index but i get the same error

Comment: python lists arent like other languages where you predefine an array size, just set it to an empty list and append the random ints into it

Comment: how about `summa=sum(n[:4])`?

Comment: taht works but how i could now multiply remaining ones

Comment: there's no multiplication mentioned in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to access index of 7 it will search for 7 which is a number not an index. Try this instead.

```
import random
n=[0]*7
for i in range(7):
    n[i]=random.randint(0,99)
    print(*n,sep=' ')
summa=0
prdct=1
for i in range(7):
    if n.index(n[i])<4:
    #calculate the sum of first 4 values
        summa=summa+n[i]
    else:
    #calculate the product of the rest values
        prdct=prdct*n[i]
print(summa)
print(prdct)
```

Comment: Thx its how i thought but forgot how i need to use n.index

Answer (score 0):

here's what you want :

```
import random

# Generate a list with random numbers and print this list
n = [random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(7)]
print(*n, sep=" ")

# If you want to sum the elements until the 4th element,
# you only keep the four first element in the array then sum them
summa = sum(n[:4])

print(summa)
```

Let me explain, so first you generate an array with random numbers. Then, with the bracket syntax, you only keep the elements to the index 3 (goes to n-1). And you simply use the `sum()` function of python.
If you need further explanations, feel free to ask !

Have a great day, Lukas.

Look at this for the array slicing : https://www.askpython.com/python/array/array-slicing-in-python